# Mongodb query by percentage

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Ok i think  i did this wrong.
This is my current collection however I need to order these by percentage.

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("505006de36314b4b27000001"),
  'status' => 'pending',
  'store_id' => new MongoId("505006de36314b4b27000000"),
  'minspendone' => '50.00',
  'cashbackone' => '1.50',
  'percentageone'▼ => '0.03',
  'minspendtwo' => '100.00',
  'cashbacktwo' => '3.00',
  'percentagetwo' => '0.03',
  'minspendthree' => '',
  'cashbackthree' => '',
  'percentagethree' => '',
  'minspendfour' => '',
  'cashbackfour' => '',
  'percentagefour' => '',
)
```

so would I better of changing it to the following

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("505006de36314b4b27000001"),
  'status' => 'pending',
  'store_id' => new MongoId("505006de36314b4b27000000"),
  'offers' => array( 
  'minspend' => '50.00',
  'cashback' => '1.50',
  'percentage' => '0.03'),
  array(
  'minspend' => '100.00',
  'cashback' => '3.00',
  'percentage' => '0.03'))
)
```

could someone please advise me.

Comment: This appears to be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398528/mongodb-sort-by-percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Russell,

If you wish to use the mongodb internal sort function you will need to split the array elements into separate documents.

Mongodb sort works to set the order of whole documents returned, rather the return order of elements within documents.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Yes but I thought we where able to do sub-array sorts

Comment: Not on the database server, it would need to be done client size. Mongodb's unit of granularity is a document, sub arrays are all elements of that one document. A sort on the contents of a sub array would need to be done on the client side.