# mongoDB sort by percentage

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, database

I know this can be done, but the issue I face is all my attempts I can't get it to work.

The percents are saved as 0.03 or 0.05 or 0.10

I tried to sort them by

```
$cursor->sort(array("offers"=>array("percentage"=>0)));
```

I have also tried

```
$cursor->sort(array("offers"=>array("cashback"=>1)));
```

but no changes.

Here is a sample collection

```
array (
  '_id'▼ => new MongoId("50513d8338fc5de706000000"),
  'test' => new MongoInt32(1),
  'offers' => 
  array (
    '0' => 
    array (
      'minspend' => '50.00',
      'cashback' => '1.50',
      'percentage' => '0.03',
    ),
    '1' => 
    array (
      'minspend' => '100.00',
      'cashback' => '3.00',
      'percentage' => '0.03',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Russell,

Sort is used to arrange the order of whole documents. Form this you look to be attempting to sort arrays within a single document.

To accomplish this you will need to retrieve the whole document and then need to write your own sort function client (PHP) side.

Please have a look at using the usort function in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php